# Including CSS for a DIV in PHP

Tags: php, css, html

```
if(boothsizerGlobal ==  3){
    var cellWidth = 112;
    var cellHeight = 52;
    var innerDivElectricTop = 41; 
    var innerDivElectricLeft =  110;    
    $('.imgBox').css("background-image", "url(booth_top_images/5X20TOP.jpg)");
    $('.imgBox').css("width", "900px");
    $('.imgBox').css("height", "225px");
    sidewalls = 2;
    backwalls = 6;  

}
```

Can anybody help me on converting above code into PHP?
I mean how to set CSS for a DIV in more than 40 if conditions I have?

Thanks

Comment: Convert javascript to php? They both work differently. Server != Browser

Comment: You're not using `cellWidth` or `cellHeight` ...

Comment: If you really want to, you can use the [`switch`](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/switch.shtml)-statement in JavaScript. Better to use than all sorts of `if`-statements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your original code made no sense to begin with as half of the declared variables weren't even being used. Furthermore, it is beyond me why you'd want to convert front-end code into server-side code like this, `php` is ***not*** the right way to do this!

```
if(boothsizerGlobal ==  3){
    $cellWidth = '112px';
    $cellHeight = '52px';
    $innerDivElectricTop = '41px'; 
    $innerDivElectricLeft =  '110px';    
    $backgroundImage = 'url(booth_top_images/5X20TOP.jpg)';

    $divCode = '<div style="width: ' . $cellWidth . '; height: ' . $cellHeight . '; "';
    return $divCode

}
```

Comment: Thanks it was useful to me

Answer (score 1):

```
.imgBox
{
background:url(booth_top_images/5X20TOP.jpg) no-repeat; 
width:900px;
height:225px;
}
```